# How to set EXPOSURE_TIME and FRAME_DURATION, CaptureRequest.Builder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME,x) dose not work

Tags: android, camera

I want to adjust the exposure time and frame duration of an Adroid phone. I read some papers saying Android doesn't provide exposure time setting API. I tried using HTC m8x phone whose camera itself support different exposure time from 4 to 1/8000, so I guess there should some way to change it in an app.

The method `get(CaptureRequest.EXPOSURE_TIME)` returns null. After I used `CaptureRequest.Builder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME,x)`, the `CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME` becomes `x`, but the preview effect in the phone doesn't change.

I checked the authority of HTC m8x, the code is as :

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
CameraManager manager =(CameraManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
  CameraCharacteristics characteristics= manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
  // We don't use a front facing camera in this sample.
  if (characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)== CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
    continue;
  }
  int level =   characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL);
  boolean hasFullLevel
                 = (level ==   CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL);



  int[] capabilities = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES);
  int syncLatency = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SYNC_MAX_LATENCY);
  boolean hasManualControl = hasCapability(capabilities,CameraCharacteristics.REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_MANUAL_SENSOR);
  boolean hasEnoughCapability = hasManualControl &&syncLatency == CameraCharacteristics.SYNC_MAX_LATENCY_PER_FRAME_CONTROL;

  // All these are guaranteed by
  // CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL, but checking for only
  // the things we care about expands range of devices we can run on
  // We want:
  //  - Back-facing camera
  //  - Manual sensor control
  //  - Per-frame synchronization (so that exposure can be changed every frame)
  if ( hasFullLevel !! hasEnoughCapability) {
    mCameraId = cameraId;
    return;}
  }
```

There is no camera id returned.

```
characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL) =2;
CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL = 1;
CameraCharacteristics.REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_MANUAL_SENSOR = 1;
capabilities =0;
characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SYNC_MAX_LATENCY) =-1
CameraCharacteristics.SYNC_MAX_LATENCY_PER_FRAME_CONTROL = 0;
```

So does this show I don't have the authority to change exposure time of HTC m8x phone? Will root the phone help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your phone ships with Android 4.x and the new camera2 API requires Lollipop/API 21.  If you have upgraded to API21, yes, if it does have full control it would tell you it does support manual exposure control... if it has limited support...

check [REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_MANUAL_SENSOR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_MANUAL_SENSOR) for the individual control you want like exposure...

if it has legacy support, no it doesn't support manual controls.